# What is the derivation of this formula of potential difference related to the capacitance of a two wire line?

Tags: voltage, capacitance, transmission-line

[image]

[image]

From this lesson: https://circuitglobe.com/capacitance-of-transmission-line.html

Basically, I don't get where the formula came from. I am aware of the V = Q / C but I'm not that familiar with capacitance especially that there are so many variations to its formula instead of having a general one. Is there a general formula or does capacitance really depend on configuration?

When it comes to the formula here used for potential difference, I would really like to know. Why is the formula constructed in such a way? Why is the coefficient at the bottom 2? I see different formulas that have 4 as the coefficient. How do I not get confused on what is the correct coefficient to use, or configuration I should refer to in capacitance. I want to be able to study this in a way that I would depend on what the general concepts are and not just memorize the formula. Thank you.

Comment: What you're asking about is the derivation of the capacitance of a transmission line, which is, while not terribly *complex*, not trivial either and would likely be the subject of one or two lectures in a class on power transmission. How familiar are you with Maxwell's equations?

Comment: I am not that familiar with Maxwell's equations but I know that it is involved in obtaining the formula for capacitance.

Comment: Assume a single wire, with a voltage V on it, ground at infinity. Solve for the cylindrically symmetric field. Add a  second wire with voltage -V, the resulting field is the superposition of both (that's why you have two ln() terms). Integrate the field to find the charge. Now you know charge and voltage, you get capacitance.